# NetworkX - graph saved on file changes edges thickness

Tags: python, file, layout, save, networkx

I am facing a little problem while trying to save my NetworkX graph on file through the "savefig" function.
My graph looks like this:

[image]

However, when I save on file, the resulting saved graph looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, in the second graph the edges are drawn normally without considering the fact that I reduced their thickness.
I'll post my code over here, maybe I'm doing something wrong:

```
# Retrieving the GCC from the undirected version of the graph
GCC = max(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(UG), key=len)
pos = nx.spring_layout(GCC,k=0.30,iterations=70, scale=2)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(GCC, pos,node_color=color_map,with_labels=True, node_size=17) #node_color=color_map, with_labels=True, node_size=17)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(GCC, pos, width=0.3)

# Saving graph in the main folder of the project
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)
fig.savefig('graph7.pdf', dpi=100)

plt.show()
```